# Ignoring all warnings in an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, warnings, suppress-warnings

Suppose that you have a bunch of projects in your Eclipse workspace. Some are Java projects, some may be CDT projects, others may come from third party plugins such as TeXlipse or EPIC. You strive long and hard to produce quality code, yet in *one* specific project you have a couple of warnings, through no fault of your own - warnings that propagate up the chain to your working set and poke you in the eye.

1. Is there a general way in Eclipse 3.7 to tell the IDE that it should ignore (and be quiet about) all warnings from a specific project, regardless of whatever support the responsible plugin may or may not provide?
2. From what I can tell, Eclipse 3.8 (or is it 4.2?) will have a better handle of warnings. Would waiting a couple of days for it to come out help at all with this specific issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can suggest is to click on the little downward-pointing triangle on the right side of the Problems View title bar.  From that drop down menu select Configure Contents.  I don't think you can filter out errors for a specific project, but you can filter out kinds of errors.

Answer (score 8):

Supernecro, but if it is still relevant, and you want to block errors because you are editing another project, right click the project and click 'close project'.

Answer (score 3):

For Java the only thing I could find is the Project Preferences -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings Page. If you set all settings to "Ignore" that project should be quiet. However it is quite cumbersome. Maybe other compilers have similar settings, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, other perspectives do not support something like this. For some it might even be impossible - for example LaTeX has some warnings that are almost impossible to silence...