# Disable eclipse warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

Is there any way to quickly disable eclipse warnings and then enable them back when I need them?

I want to be able to do some testing and am not interested in clean code in this stage, so I'd like to disable them and, after I'm done, re-enable as they were.
Just to be specific, I'm familiar with suppress warning and with changing them from preferences, this is not what I have in mind.

I want some keyboard shortcut, use it to disable all warnings, make some messy testing code + breakpoints that would be hidden behind warnings, and then after I'm done, re-enable them.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202561/ignoring-all-warnings-in-an-eclipse-project) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624756/how-can-i-disable-compiler-warnings-in-eclipse-on-a-file-specific-basis).

Comment: Even Java code that contains errors will be compiled and is executable (as long as _Treat above errors like fatal compile errors_ is disabled). So why not just ignore them?